# Scanning/Reading internal Excel xml file app.xml with perl

Tags: xml, excel, perl

I am reading the contents of an Excel file (extension .xlsx) which is a collection of XML files contained within a zip file.

I am trying to read some of these internal XML files with Perl. A basic `app.xml` file that I'm trying to read is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
  <Application>Microsoft Excel</Application>
  <DocSecurity>0</DocSecurity>
  <ScaleCrop>false</ScaleCrop>
  <HeadingPairs>
    <vt:vector size="4" baseType="variant">
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:lpstr>Worksheets</vt:lpstr>
      </vt:variant>
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:i4>4</vt:i4>
      </vt:variant>
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:lpstr>Named Ranges</vt:lpstr>
      </vt:variant>
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:i4>2</vt:i4>
      </vt:variant>
    </vt:vector>
  </HeadingPairs>
  <TitlesOfParts>
    <vt:vector size="6" baseType="lpstr">
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet1</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet2</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet3</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet4</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet3</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Test1</vt:lpstr>
    </vt:vector>
  </TitlesOfParts>
  <Company/>
  <LinksUpToDate>false</LinksUpToDate>
  <SharedDoc>false</SharedDoc>
  <HyperlinksChanged>false</HyperlinksChanged>
  <AppVersion>16.0300</AppVersion>
</Properties>
```

The section `<HeadingPairs>` contains two parts

- All non-hidden Worksheets within the Excel file
- All the Named Ranges

I need to change some of the sheet name values and need to know whether
the `Worksheets` subsection of the `HeadingPairs` element will *always* be first in an arbitrary Excel file.

If it is not always first then I have a problem. I cannot scan for it in general as I deal with Excel files in multiple languages and for each language the word `Worksheets` is translated.

I have looked for documentation of structure or schemas for the `app.xml` file but have not found anything that helps.

Comment: [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) Part 1, page 3737, §22.2.2.8

Comment: OK, if i'm reading your referenced section correctly (I think it's page 3727 where §22.2.2.8 resides) then there is no constraint on the ordering.

Comment: Please avoid using HTML markup in Stack Overflow questions where possible. We use [*Markdown*](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting here.